# Reference request: trace norm estimate

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, integral-operators

In a paper I am currently reading, the author uses that if $T$ is an operator given by the kernel $$T(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb R} p(x,z) q(z,y) dz,$$
then $$\lvert \operatorname{tr} T \rvert \leq \lVert T \rVert_1 \leq \int_{\mathbb R} \lVert p(\cdot,z) \rVert_{L^2} \lVert q(z,\cdot) \rVert_{L^2} dz,$$ where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ denotes the trace norm. It is clear to me that for each fixed $z$, the operator given by the kernel $p(x,z)q(z,y)$ is a rank one operator with trace norm $\lVert p(\cdot,z) \rVert_{L^2} \lVert q(z,\cdot) \rVert_{L^2}$. How does one proceed? I assume maybe one can view $\int_{\mathbb R} p(\cdot,z) q(z,\cdot) dz$ as some $L^2(\mathbb R \times \mathbb R)$-valued integral. I am sure there must be some reference where the details are given. I am also curious whether there exist similar estimates for Schatten (semi-)norms $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ with $p\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: If you replace the integral with a sum, the result follows by the triangle inequality for the trace class norm. Some approximation should give the result...it looks like Minkowski inequality for integrals, for the trace class norm.